# "undefined reference to" error during linking process

Tags: fortran, mpi, llvm, lapack, blas

I am building my application using OpenMPI (built with LLVM) and few other external libraries including netcdf-fortran, BLAS and LAPACK. The files compile without any problem, but in the last stage where all the object files are being linked I get the following error

```
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: _rad_8_
>>> referenced by buildings_rad_walls.f90:26 (/home/rangke/archive/gsam1.4/SRC/BUILDINGS/buildings_rad_walls.f90:26)
>>>               buildings_rad_walls.o:(buildings_rad_walls_)
>>> referenced by buildings_rad_walls.f90:0 (/home/rangke/archive/gsam1.4/SRC/BUILDINGS/buildings_rad_walls.f90:0)
>>>               buildings_rad_walls.o:(buildings_rad_walls_)
>>> referenced by buildings_rad_walls.f90:0 (/home/rangke/archive/gsam1.4/SRC/BUILDINGS/buildings_rad_walls.f90:0)
>>>               buildings_rad_walls.o:(buildings_rad_walls_)
>>> referenced 69 more times
>>> did you mean: _rad_0_
>>> defined in: rad.o
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The error message indicates that lines of 0 and 26 in `/home/rangke/archive/gsam1.4/SRC/BUILDINGS/buildings_rad_walls.f90` references `_rad8_`, but this file does not contain nor any of my files contain a variable named `_rad_8_`. Line 0 in the file is a comment, and the line 26 contains the following

```
if(doshadows.and.flag_sunny) then
```

which has nothing to do with the `_rad_8_`. `doshadows` and `flag_sunny` are logical data type, not an integer or real or double data type.

The following is the linking part of my makefile content.

```
LD = mpifort
LDFLAGS = -${ncf_dir}/lib -lnetcdff -lblas -llapack
...
...
...
$(LD) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

where `${ncf_dir}` is the netcdf-fortran directory.

I am suspecting that the variable `_rad_8_` has to do with BLAS or LAPACK, specifically something with data type precision. I have tried different BLAS and LAPACK library, such as BLIS and libflame, but to no avail. Does anyone have any idea what is happening here? Any idea would help.

**More clues.**

What I have found out is that when I put `-fdefault-real-8` flag so that every real is treated as 8 byte, I get the following error message

```
mpifort -c -O3 -Mpreprocess -Mextend -mcmodel=large -march=znver2 -r8 -I/usr/include /home/rangke/archive/gsam1.4/SRC/zero.f90
/tmp/rad-9b513e.ll:36:1: error: invalid use of function-local name
%struct_rad_8_ = type < { [4 x i8]  } > 
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [/home/rangke/archive/gsam1.4/makefile:62: rad.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

This error mesage contains the `_rad_8_` in question, but I am not sure where it is from. It seems like this error message is for the `/home/rangke/archive/gsam1.4/SRC/zero.f90`, but according to the make output it is produced during the compilation of `rad.o` which is different file.

Where is this

```
%struct_rad_8_ = type < { [4 x i8]  } >
```

from? I can confidently say that it is not part of my application, it is not in `/home/rangke/archive/gsam1.4/SRC/zero.f90` or in the `rad.f90` file.

**More more clues**

I found that `_rad_8_` comes from LLVM IR (bit code). I have compiled the same code on AMD 4750U and AMD EPYC 7513, and they produce different LLVM IR codes. In short EPYC 7513 produces `%struct_rad_8_ = type < { [4 x i8]  } >`, and eventually leads to successful linking process of my application, while AMD 4750U does not. Why is this happening? Is this problem inherent to the AMD CPU generations? Or is there a way to force AMD 4750U to gerenate the `%struct_rad_8_ = type < { [4 x i8]  } >` part? I have listed the detailed LLVM IR issue in the AMD forum : https://community.amd.com/t5/processors/different-llvm-ir-content-for-the-same-code-on-different-zen/td-p/610733

Comment: I could not find any `rad_8_` symbol in the LLVM runtime so this is pretty suspicious. make sure you use `implicit none` **everywhere** to make sure the compiler can spot this kind of typo.

Comment: Yeah. I did make sure to add `implicit none` on every file. Though, I am getting the same error. I am trying to gernerate some more detailed debug message. `-g` flag does not seem to work at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: what does line 26 of `/home/rangke/archive/gsam1.4/SRC/BUILDINGS/buildings_rad_walls.f90` contains? just in case, try removing the object file and run `make` again in order to make sure the file is needed and was rebuilt.

Comment: In some configurations, you would need to `-lnetcdff -lnetcdf` and link with lapack first `-llapack -lblas`. this is very likely unrelated to this issue though.

Comment: The content of the line 26 is shown in the main question. It is just a if statement with two logical data types.

Comment: Regarding the libs order, it does not seem to do the trick..

Comment: did you rebuild? what if you you write instead `if(doshadows) then if (flag_sunny) then ...`? (add some extra blank lines before to make sure the line number is updated.

Comment: Did clean rebuild, even with your if statment suggestion. But I am getting the same error.

Comment: same line number after you added some empty lines before?

Comment: The error line number changes when I do that, so when that if statement is in line 30, then the error message corresponds to it.

Comment: mpifort is just a convenience command - presumably it preprocesses the code in some way and then uses a normal compiler to build it.  At a guess line 26 refers to line 26 of the pre-processed code.  Is there any way of seeing what that is, say with a -E parameter?  I don't really know which compiler mpifort is targetting on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. As it turns out, I did not assign enough MPI process numbers for the memory work out. So, it did not have to with CPU architecture or linker.